# Micronaut - Persist WebSocketSession to redis

Tags: websocket, redis, micronaut

I am trying to persist my WebsocketSessions on Redis and then succesfully broadcast messages to all my active sessions.
Following the documentation:

1. https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#websocket
2. https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#sessions
3. https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-redis/latest/guide/#sessions

I would expect when I have the following code on my `ServerWebSocket`, the WebSocket session to be stored automatically on Redis.

```
@OnOpen
fun onOpen(branchId: Long, session: WebSocketSession) {
   session.put(USER_SESSION_KEY, user.id)
   session.put(BRANCH_SESSION_KEY, branch.id)
       ...
   session.sendAsync("smth")
}
```

And then whenever I call the broadcaster, I am expecting the message to be broadcasted to all the open stored-redis-sessions that match the given predicate.

```
webSocketBroadcaster.broadcastAsync(
            webSocketMessage,
            shouldSendMessageForSession(order)
        )

private fun shouldSendMessageForSession(order: OrdersEntity) = Predicate<WebSocketSession> { session ->
        val userId = session[USER_SESSION_KEY, Long::class.java].toNullable() ?: return@Predicate false
        val user = userEntityRepository.findById(userId).toNullable() ?: return@Predicate false
        val branchId = session[BRANCH_SESSION_KEY, Long::class.java].toNullable() ?: return@Predicate false
        return@Predicate order.branchId == branchId && order.canAccessWithUser(user)
    }
```

Sadly this is not happening or I am missing something :( Has anyone found a solution for this?

1. Is this supported?
2. If yes, do i need to do something else in order, my broadcaster, to be aware of all the sessions stored on Redis?
3. Is there a way to serialize|persist a webSocketSession?

Thank you!